# Custom checkbox selection limit is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Since i have designed the custom checkbox, i wanted to limit the checkbox. I could easily add limits for default checkbox but in my case its not working because of my own design & I have no idea about custom checkbox selection limits. Please help me to get out off it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btcp-multi-lst').on('change', function(evt) {
    if ($('input').is(':checked').length >= 3) {
      this.checked = false;
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.checkbox{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.checkbox>label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px; 
    color: #686868;
    padding-top: 2px;
    min-height: 25px;
    font-family: 'montserrat';
}
.checkbox>span{
  padding-right: 17px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}
.checkbox>label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 0;
  top:4px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /*background-color: #ccc;*/
  -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
    /*z-index:25156332;*/
    
}
.checkbox>label::after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  left: 0;
  top: 4px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #555555; 
      /*z-index:25156332;*/
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  }
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px; 
    
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
  color: #1E6C97;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f00c";   
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
  opacity: 0.65; 
    
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label::before {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  cursor: not-allowed; 
    
}
.checkbox.checkbox-circle label::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  }
.checkbox.checkbox-inline {
  margin-top: 0; 
    
}
.fltr-chk-box-bg{
  background-color: #E3E7EA;
  color: #1E6C97;
}
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #1E6C97;
  border-color: #428bca;
  }
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  color: #fff; 
    
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label + span{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 75456;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label + span:before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 border-bottom: 13px solid #CCD2D6;
 border-top: 11px solid #CCD2D6;
 border-right: 50px solid #CCD2D6;
 border-left: 6px solid transparent;
 z-index: -7523;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/aacdcb9275.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="well btcp-multi-lst bg-white margin-btm-0" id="scrollbar">
    <form>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category1" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category1">Manufacturer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category2" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category2">Trading Company</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category3" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category3">Distributor / Merchant / Stockist</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category4" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category4">Wholesaler / Dealer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category5" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category5">Exporter</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category6" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category6">Converter</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category7" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category7">Broker</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category8" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category8">Direct Seller</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category9" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category9">Retailer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category10" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category10">Indenting Agent / Buying Office / Purchasing Agent</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category11" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category11">Carrying & Forwarding Agent</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category12" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category12">Packers</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category13" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category13">Printers</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category14" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category14">Recycling Company</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category15" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category15">Service Provider</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category16" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category16">Warehousing Company</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category17" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category17">Logistics Provider</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category18" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category18">Mining Company</label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: In what way is it not working, what's going wrong?

Comment: Did you mean to ask: ***"How to limit the number of checked checkboxes"***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is(':checked')` function returns a single, boolean value, which on you can't use `length` property.

Suggested approach would be selecting all the checked checkboxes with `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 1)` selector. If their amount is bigger than e.g. `1`, disable other checkboxes.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btcp-multi-lst').on('change', function(e) {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 1) {
      $('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.checkbox{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.checkbox>label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px; 
    color: #686868;
    padding-top: 2px;
    min-height: 25px;
    font-family: 'montserrat';
}
.checkbox>span{
  padding-right: 17px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}
.checkbox>label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 0;
  top:4px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /*background-color: #ccc;*/
  -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
    /*z-index:25156332;*/
    
}
.checkbox>label::after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  left: 0;
  top: 4px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #555555; 
      /*z-index:25156332;*/
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  }
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px; 
    
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
  color: #1E6C97;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f00c";   
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
  opacity: 0.65; 
    
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label::before {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  cursor: not-allowed; 
    
}
.checkbox.checkbox-circle label::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  }
.checkbox.checkbox-inline {
  margin-top: 0; 
    
}
.fltr-chk-box-bg{
  background-color: #E3E7EA;
  color: #1E6C97;
}
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #1E6C97;
  border-color: #428bca;
  }
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  color: #fff; 
    
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label + span{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 75456;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label + span:before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 border-bottom: 13px solid #CCD2D6;
 border-top: 11px solid #CCD2D6;
 border-right: 50px solid #CCD2D6;
 border-left: 6px solid transparent;
 z-index: -7523;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/aacdcb9275.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="well btcp-multi-lst bg-white margin-btm-0" id="scrollbar">
    <form>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category1" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category1">Manufacturer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category2" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category2">Trading Company</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category3" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category3">Distributor / Merchant / Stockist</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category4" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category4">Wholesaler / Dealer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category5" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category5">Exporter</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category6" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category6">Converter</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category7" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category7">Broker</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category8" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category8">Direct Seller</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category9" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category9">Retailer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category10" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category10">Indenting Agent / Buying Office / Purchasing Agent</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category11" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category11">Carrying & Forwarding Agent</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category12" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category12">Packers</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category13" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category13">Printers</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category14" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category14">Recycling Company</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category15" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category15">Service Provider</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category16" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category16">Warehousing Company</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category17" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category17">Logistics Provider</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category18" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category18">Mining Company</label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a few changes to your selectors because they were a bit off, also you have to use `evt.target` in order to actually pinpoint which input is being targeted in order to set your limit. If you want a maximum of 2 checked boxes, then change the `>` to `>=` just like in your original code, if you want a maximum of 3 leave it just like that.

```
$('.btcp-multi-lst').on('click', function(evt) {
    if ($(this).find('input:checked').length > 3) {
      $(evt.target).prop("checked", false);
    };
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jojdy006/)

Cheers

Comment: You missed a great opportunity to make your checkboxes visually, UI *"disabled"* - instead it looks from a user perspective like the code broke suddenly :D

Comment: Yeah, wasn't really thinking into doing more than what was required by the OP, and yes it does look that way :P

Answer (score 0):

Your selection of `checked` ones is wrong.

Firstly you should change the selection for binding `change` event:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(evt) {
```

And then change the selection for `checked` ones:

```
$('form input[type=checkbox]:checked').length
```

Last, you should compare with your limit plus 1. Because when you check a checkbox, the length of checked ones is now (limit + 1). After setting `this.checked = false`, the length is limit now.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(evt) {
  var limit = 3;
  
    if ($('form input[type=checkbox]:checked').length >= limit + 1) {
    console.log('before: ' + $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length);
      this.checked = false;
     console.log('after: ' + $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length);
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.checkbox{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.checkbox>label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px; 
    color: #686868;
    padding-top: 2px;
    min-height: 25px;
    font-family: 'montserrat';
}
.checkbox>span{
  padding-right: 17px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}
.checkbox>label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 0;
  top:4px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /*background-color: #ccc;*/
  -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
    /*z-index:25156332;*/
    
}
.checkbox>label::after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  left: 0;
  top: 4px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #555555; 
      /*z-index:25156332;*/
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  }
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px; 
    
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
  color: #1E6C97;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f00c";   
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
  opacity: 0.65; 
    
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label::before {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  cursor: not-allowed; 
    
}
.checkbox.checkbox-circle label::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  }
.checkbox.checkbox-inline {
  margin-top: 0; 
    
}
.fltr-chk-box-bg{
  background-color: #E3E7EA;
  color: #1E6C97;
}
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #1E6C97;
  border-color: #428bca;
  }
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  color: #fff; 
    
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label + span{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 75456;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label + span:before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 border-bottom: 13px solid #CCD2D6;
 border-top: 11px solid #CCD2D6;
 border-right: 50px solid #CCD2D6;
 border-left: 6px solid transparent;
 z-index: -7523;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/aacdcb9275.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="well btcp-multi-lst bg-white margin-btm-0" id="scrollbar">
    <form>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category1" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category1">Manufacturer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category2" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category2">Trading Company</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category3" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category3">Distributor / Merchant / Stockist</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category4" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category4">Wholesaler / Dealer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category5" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category5">Exporter</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category6" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category6">Converter</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category7" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category7">Broker</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category8" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category8">Direct Seller</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category9" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category9">Retailer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category10" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category10">Indenting Agent / Buying Office / Purchasing Agent</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category11" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category11">Carrying & Forwarding Agent</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category12" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category12">Packers</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category13" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category13">Printers</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category14" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category14">Recycling Company</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category15" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category15">Service Provider</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category16" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category16">Warehousing Company</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category17" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category17">Logistics Provider</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="category18" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category18">Mining Company</label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to

## Limit number of checked checkboxes

```js
// P.S: Use your desired selector to target your checkboxes:

var $ckb = $(":checkbox[name^=c]").on("change", function(){

  var $checked = $ckb.filter(":checked");
  $ckb.not($checked).prop("disabled", $checked.length >= 3);

});
```

```css
label{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="c1"> Test 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="c2"> Test 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="c3"> Test 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="c4"> Test 4</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="c5"> Test 5</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

Add the class "limited-cb" to your input checkboxes tags.

```
 <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input class="limited-cb" id="category1" type="checkbox" value=""> <label for="category1">Manufacturer</label>
        </div>
```

Use this jQuery not to let the 4th checkbox be clicked.

```
$(".limited-cb").click( function(){
        var checkedCount = 0;
        var acceptCheck = false;
        var $cbs = $(".limited-cb");
        for(var i=0; i< $cbs.length; i++){
            var $cb = $cbs.eq(i);
            if($cb.prop("checked") === true){
                checkedCount++;
                if(checkedCount <= 3){
                    acceptCheck = true;
                }else{
                    acceptCheck = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(acceptCheck === false){
            $(this).prop("checked",false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `for(var i=0; i< $cbs.length; i++){ var $cb = $cbs.eq(i);` why would you want to do that :D ? Also to you goes the same comment as for Lixus's answer

Comment: It is one way of doing it. Any way that lets you know if this cb is the 4th in order to reject it will work.